# Radare2 Call $+5 and register-based cross-references not found

Tags: disassembly, radare2

I have a library of ~65MB which uses this "technique" as a kind of PIC.

First, it gets some kind of base address (it is always the same):

```
0x00708497      e800000000     call 0x70849c
0x0070849c      5b             pop ebx
0x0070849d      81c3ac442601   add ebx, 0x12644ac
```

And then it's used to reference strings or global variables:

```
0x007084bc      8d832e29a8ff   lea eax, [ebx - 0x57d6d2]
```

So, is there any analysis command which could find these references?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues on radare's GitHub about such code, e.g.:

[Invalid strings xref in x86](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/6819)

[String(DATA) xref does not work with x86 binary built with -fPIC -m32](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/6402)

According to some comments on them, `aae` is supposed to resolve such references after [this change](https://github.com/radare/radare2/pull/6902), so try it. If not, open a new issue or try other [support options](https://github.com/radare/radare2#pointers).

Comment: I will create a issue once I make a smaller library reproducing the issue, for now I made a [python script](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1765072) using r2pipe to find these references

Comment: @FabianMendez so, have you found a way to do a smaller reproducer? Opening an issue even just "as is" can help too.

Comment: @AntonKochkov There is an issue already: https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/11309